# Why isn't magento finding my adminhtml grid block?

Tags: adminhtml, grid, blocks

I'm trying to build my first admin grid.

The tutorial I'm following is http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

The routing-to-the-controller part is working. When I open my URL, I see the title set using `$this->title()`.

**controllers/Adminhtml/Shipments/ReportController.php**

```
    $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('ebuynow_ebnreports/adminhtml_shipments_report');
    $this->_addContent($block);
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Shipments/Report.php**, `Ebuynow_Ebnreports_Adminhtml_Shipments_Report::__construct()`

```
    $this->_blockGroup = 'ebuynow_ebnreports';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_shipments_report';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('ebuynow_ebnreports')
        ->__('sum headertext');
    parent::__construct();
    $this->removeButton('add');
```

And the grid file is located **Block/Adminhtml/Shipments/Report/Grid.php** and has class `Ebuynow_Ebnreports_Block_Adminhtml_Shipments_Report_Grid`. I've been looking at this for a while, and it all looks like it matches up with the inchoo tutorial code.

When I open the page with developer mode turned on, I get this error

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_addContent() 
>   must be an instance of `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`, boolean given

The `createBlock()` call is not able to find the block using that string and I don't see why.

If more information is needed I can add more code, I just figured this was where the error was.

Possibly relevant: I followed the execution path of `createBlock()` to see what it was looking for given the string `ebuynow_ebnreports/adminhtml_shipments_report`. In **Mage/Core/Model/Config.php** `::getGroupedClassName()`, I echoed `$className` at the end, before the return and for this: `Mage_Ebuynow_Ebnreports_Block_Adminhtml_Shipments_Report`

It seems to be prefixing my block class name with `Mage_`. Not sure if that's normal or not but seems odd. I tried adding `Mage_` to my actual block's class name and it didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

The solution was to add the following block in **config.xml**:

```
    <blocks>
        <ebuynow_ebnreports>
            <class>Ebuynow_Ebnreports_Block</class>
        </ebuynow_ebnreports>
    </blocks>
```